# Get collection without deleted resources API-Platform

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

How can I select a resource without it's releted resources deleted using API-Platform ?
I have this relation Don ManyTOOne Donateur. In the Don resouce, I have $isDeleted as field. When its value is true, and a try to select a item form Donateur, I get it.
Show here:

```
// The GET operation http://localhost:8000/api/donateurs/3
{
  "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Donateur",
  "@id": "\/api\/donateurs\/3",
  "@type": "Donateur",
  "id": 3,
  "nom": "Yazid Ibn Amr",
  "solde": 135000,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "dons": [
    {
      "@id": "\/api\/dons\/1",
      "@type": "Don",
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2021-07-26T00:00:00+00:00",
      "montant": 35000,
      "isDeleted": true
    },
    {
      "@id": "\/api\/dons\/2",
      "@type": "Don",
      "id": 2,
      "date": "2021-07-28T00:00:00+00:00",
      "montant": 60000,
      "isDeleted": false
    },
    {
      "@id": "\/api\/dons\/3",
      "@type": "Don",
      "id": 3,
      "date": "2021-07-28T00:00:00+00:00",
      "montant": 75000,
      "isDeleted": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't need deleted resource in this returned collection of Don when getting a Donateur item.

Here is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\DonRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "read:Don:item",
 *              "read:Don:collection"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      denormalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "write:Don"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get", "post"
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "normalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={
 *                      "read:Don:item",
 *                      "read:Don:collection"
 *                  }
 *              }
 *          }, 
 *          "patch", "delete"
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DonRepository::class)
 */
class Don
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read:Donateur:item"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Donateur::class, inversedBy="dons")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"read:Don:collection", "write:Don"})
     */
    private $donateur;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"read:Don:collection", "write:Don", "read:Donateur:item"})
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Groups({"read:Don:collection", "write:Don", "read:Donateur:item"})
     */
    private $montant;
```

And

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\DonateurRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "read:Donateur:item",
 *              "read:Donateur:collection"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      denormalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "write:Donateur"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get", "post"
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get", "patch", "delete"
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DonateurRepository::class)
 */
class Donateur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("read:Donateur:collection")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"read:Donateur:collection", "write:Donateur"})
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"read:Donateur:collection", "write:Donateur"})
     */
    private $presentation;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Groups({"read:Donateur:collection", "write:Don"})
     */
    private $solde;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Groups("read:Donateur:collection")
     */
    private $isDeleted;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
     */
    private $createdBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
     */
    private $updatedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
     */
    private $deletedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Don::class, mappedBy="donateur")
     * @Groups({"read:Donateur:item"})
     */
    private $dons;
```

And this one

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryCollectionExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryItemExtensionInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use App\Entity\Don;
use App\Entity\Donateur;
use App\Entity\TypeOeuvre;

class NoneDeletedResources implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface, QueryItemExtensionInterface
{
    public function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass)
    {
        if($resourceClass === TypeOeuvre::class or $resourceClass === Don::class or $resourceClass === Donateur::class){
            $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
            $queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.isDeleted = :isDeleted");
            $queryBuilder->orderBy("$rootAlias.id", "DESC");
            $queryBuilder->setParameter("isDeleted", false);
        }
    }

    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, ?string $operationName = null)
    {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }
    
    public function applyToItem(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, array $identifiers, ?string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
    {
        // dd($context);
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Did my answer help you? If not, please let me know how I can improve my answer.

Comment: It's working for this relation. But when I try to execute an other it doesn't work and I get an error.

Comment: Of course, I didn't write all of your queries ;) But glad to hear it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.isDeleted = :isDeleted");
```

With this code, you're only filtering on the root alias, not on its relations. You should alter your code in such a way that it filters on those relations as well.

```
public function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass)
{
    if($resourceClass === Donateur::class) {
        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
        $queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.isDeleted = :isDeleted");
        $queryBuilder->orderBy("$rootAlias.id", "DESC");
        $queryBuilder->setParameter("isDeleted", false);

        // add something like this:
        $queryBuilder->andWhere("dons.isDeleted = :isDeleted");
    }
}
```

The exact name of the alias (I used `dons` as an example) depends on your use case. Maybe you should join `Don` before you can use it.

I hope you can use my suggestion to fix your problem. If not, please let me know; I'll help with adding some implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass)
    {
        if($resourceClass === TypeOeuvre::class or $resourceClass === Don::class or $resourceClass === Donateur::class or $resourceClass === Oeuvre::class or $resourceClass === DonOeuvre::class){
            $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
            if($resourceClass === Donateur::class) {
                $queryBuilder->join("$rootAlias.dons", "d");
                $queryBuilder->andWhere("d.isDeleted = :isDeleted");
            }

            if($resourceClass === Oeuvre::class or $resourceClass === Don::class) {
                $queryBuilder->join("$rootAlias.donOeuvres", "d");
                $queryBuilder->andWhere("d.isDeleted = :isDeleted");
                // dd($queryBuilder);
            }
            $queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.isDeleted = :isDeleted");
            $queryBuilder->orderBy("$rootAlias.id", "DESC");
            $queryBuilder->setParameter("isDeleted", false);
        }
    }
```

The first if is working correctly. But not the second
This is my resources code:

Don.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\DonRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "read:Don:item",
 *              "read:Don:collection"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      denormalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "write:Don"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get", "post"
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "normalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={
 *                      "read:Don:item",
 *                      "read:Don:collection"
 *                  }
 *              }
 *          }, 
 *          "utilisation_don" = {
 *              "path" = "/{id}/utilisation-don,
 *              "controller" =
 *          }
 *          "patch", "delete"
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DonRepository::class)
 */
class Don
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read:Donateur:item"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DonOeuvre::class, mappedBy="don")
     */
    private $donOeuvres;
```

Oeuvre.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use App\Repository\OeuvreRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "read:Oeuvre:collection"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      denormalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "write:Oeuvre"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get", 
 *          "post" = {
 *              "denormalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={
 *                      "write:Oeuvre"
 *                  }
*               }
 *          }
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get", 
 *          "patch" = {
 *              "denormalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={
 *                      "update:Oeuvre:patch"
 *                  }
*               }
 *          }, 
 *          "delete"
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OeuvreRepository::class)
 */
class Oeuvre
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("read:Oeuvre:collection")
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DonOeuvre::class, mappedBy="oeuvre")
     * @Groups({"write:Oeuvre"})
     */
    private $donOeuvres;
```

and DonOeuvre.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\DonOeuvreRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "read:DonOeuvre:collection"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      denormalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={
 *              "write:DonOeuvre"
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get", "post"
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get", "patch", "delete"
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DonOeuvreRepository::class)
 */
class DonOeuvre
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read:DonOeuvre:collection", "read:Don:item"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Don::class, inversedBy="donOeuvres")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"read:DonOeuvre:collection", "write:DonOeuvre", "write:Oeuvre"})
     */
    private $don;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Oeuvre::class, inversedBy="donOeuvres", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"read:DonOeuvre:collection", "write:DonOeuvre", "read:Don:item"})
     */
    private $oeuvre;
```